# Sequence of Activities - Interactive book

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to make an interactive book, where every page contains 2 images and 2 buttons.
One image is animated on user touch (that's working fine)
The buttons are "Back" and "Next", that's working fine too, but my problem is I have a sequence of 10 classes name one after another:

Class01
Class02
Class03...
(Every class has a different animation)

So in class01, next button is always calling the next activity

```
 public void Next(View v) {
    Intent next = new Intent(this, next_page);
    startActivity(next);
    finish();
```

and closing the current one, which is Force Closing the app quite regularly.
I'm new to android and I think my logic is pretty useless.

How can I implement this sequence?

Comment: better go for view pager than using menu classes..

Comment: Are you declaring the activities in the application manifest? Every `Activity` that your application uses must be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make it using View Flipper to make it more interactive and add animations.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `finish();` isn't necessary, remove it. And you will have:

**Next button**

```
public void Next(View v) {
    Intent next = new Intent(this, next_page);
    startActivity(next);
}
```

**Back button**

```
public void Back(View v) {
    this.finish();
}
```

Don't forget, users can press "Back Button" on their device. This may interest you:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
     // do something if the button back is pressed.
     super.onBackPressed();
}
```

---

I think *@MohammedSaleem* and *@mvnpavan* are right when they say you should to use `ViewFlipper`, more adapted in your case. You will declare in your `Manifest` **just one** `Activity` for all your layouts. See this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3545954/2668136) which says:

> ViewFlipper can be used if you want to periodically change the views.
>   Say like an automated flipping book of some sort.

To make a `ViewFlipper`, you must to read this tutorial:
[Creating Image Slideshow Using ViewFlipper](http://javatechig.com/android/android-viewflipper-example)

And to see a simple example in this SO answer:
[How To Use ViewFlipper With Three Layouts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871570/2668136)

Finally, the Google Reference Documentation:
[Public Class ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html)

Hope this help.